# How can I limit the number of rows of a query based on a calculated number?

Tags: mysql, limit

Say I want to return info about 10% of countries and the number of countries potentially varies.

Currently I'm using two queries like this; the first to determine the number of countries (i.e. 10% of the total number) for which I want to return info:

```
SELECT ROUND(COUNT(countries)*0.1)
FROM countries;
```

The second query should return the info:

```
SELECT countries, money/people AS 'PerCapitaMoney'
FROM countries
ORDER BY money/people
LIMIT 21;  -- This is the result of the first query
```

Is it possible to write one query to return this info *and* limit the number of rows as intended?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: You should be able to have a subquery to determine this 10% number and use it to determine which countries to list and which ones not to. But as @Strawberry said without any data and table descriptions we really can't create a query to demonstrate. Good luck.

Comment: In that case, all the information you need to answer the question yourself must also be in the question. You have no further need for assistance. Suggest you close the question forthwith.

Answer (score 0):

The LIMIT value can only be a literal integer, not an expression, the result of another query, or the value of a mysql variable.

***Source:*** https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch03s20.html